# Errors Implementing Dirichlet Boundary Conditions in PDE with NDSolve

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, numerical-integration, pde

I am trying to solve the Laplace equation in 2D. Denote by u(x,y) the solution. I am implementing Dirichlet BC's  on two boundaries, one inner (where u=1) and one outer (where u=0). The shape of the inner boundary is described implicitly. I would like to solve the equation in the region between the two boundaries.

[Shape of Solution Region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eaypf.png)

To ensure accuracy near the inner boundary, I would like to explicitly generate a mesh and control its properties. To do this, I followed [this documentation (Numerical Regions Section )](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html), adapted to my problem:

```
"geometrical parameters and relations";
r1 = (z0^2 - r0^2)/(2 r0);
R0 = (r0^2 + z0^2)/(2 r0);

r0 = 1; z0 = 2; rOut = 10; uIn = 1; uOut = 0;

"define mesh (adapted from linked documentation)";
<< NDSolve`FEM`;
reg1 = Region[Disk[{0, 0}, rOut]];
reg2 = Region[ImplicitRegion[(Sqrt[r^2] + r1)^2 + z^2 < R0^2, {r, z}]];

solnReg = RegionDifference[reg1, reg2];

nr = ToNumericalRegion[solnReg];

bm1 = ToBoundaryMesh[reg1];
bm2 = ToBoundaryMesh[reg2, PrecisionGoal -> 6];

bele1 = bm1["BoundaryElements"];
bele2 = bm2["BoundaryElements"];

bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> Join[bm1["Coordinates"], bm2["Coordinates"]], 
   "BoundaryElements" -> 
    Join[bele1, 
     MapThread[#1[#2] &, {Head /@ bele2, 
       Length[bm1["Coordinates"]] + ElementIncidents[bele2]}]],
   "MeshOrder" -> 1
   ];

SetNumericalRegionElementMesh[nr, bmesh];
mesh = ToElementMesh[nr];

"plot mesh";
{mesh["Wireframe"], 
 mesh["Wireframe"[PlotRange -> 2 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]]}
```

[Explicitly Defined Mesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PCVU.png)

Next I set the BC's and solve the equation:

```
"inner BC";
bc1 = DirichletCondition[
   u[r, z] == uIn, (Sqrt[r^2] + r1)^2 + z^2 == R0^2];

"outer BC";
bc2 = DirichletCondition[u[r, z] == uOut, r^2 + z^2 == rOut^2];

"solve PDE and plot solution";
sol = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[u[r, z], {r, z}] == 0, bc1, bc2}, 
   u, Element[{r, z}, mesh], 
   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> "FiniteElement"}];

GraphicsRow[{ContourPlot[sol[r, z], {r, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}, 
   PlotRange -> {0, 1}], 
  Plot3D[sol[r, z], {r, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]}]
```

[Points Near Boundary Take Wrong Values! (Red Arrows)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRJEB.jpg)

When I do this, however, I get that some of the points near the boundary are dramatically wrong (indicated by red arrows in the above image), so the solution looks "ragged" in this area.

I have messed around with various options of ToBoundaryMesh[], e.g. explicitly providing it with boundary points, increasing precision/accuracy targets, changing the mesh order. I have also played with the Method parameter in the NDSolve, but that didn't improve the situation either. Finally, if I instead feed NDSolve[] the region solnReg that I defined above, and let the function generate a mesh automatically, I see the same issue.

I am using Mathematica 13.2 on OSX Ventura 13.2.1.

Any help you can provide would be very welcome! Also, this is my first time posting so please let me know if I need to provide any extra information or context.

Comment: Oh, never mind. The solution is right, when evaluated at the vertices of the mesh. Those weird edges are caused by something funny happening in between the vertices, where the interpolating function changes rapidly (apparently)